# Unable to see Summary post the Jmeter Load test in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, jmeter

I have my JMeter `.jmx` file with all the requests for the Load test in Visual Studio Team Services. When the run is complete, I do not see a summary report or a graph generated for the run.

[image: Screenshot of the Run]

In the Diagnostics tab i see a warning message as

Jmeter.util.SSLManager:Keystore file not found;loading empty keystore

Could this warning be the issue, if so how do i get rid of this?

[image: Warning Message]

Comment: Are there summary results when you do load test in local?

Comment: @starain: Yes i have the Summary report Listener and i do see the summary results.

Comment: What's your detail steps to create jmeter load test?

Comment: @starain: Here are the details I first create a `jmx` file in JMeter with a http GET request pointing to my AUT with Summary report and Aggregate graph as listener and run the test to verify. Later on i use the same `jmx` file to import in my Visual Studio Load test by specifying the run time and agents. Please let me know if there is anything else needed on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of this issue is that your test is running for a very short duration. So, to deal with this issue, you can change Loop Count to Forever in Apach JMeter and specify Load Duration in JMeter load test in VSTS.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @starain , checking the Loop count to Forever did the trick. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to display the summary report or graph generated by listeners in VSTS Web Portal. If you want to see the information, click "Download Results" link and open the .csv file in it from Apache JMeter. Refer to Step 10 in this link for details: [Run Apache JMeter load tests with Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/get-started-jmeter-test).

> 10. If you have a favorite listener that you use to analyze results in the JMeter IDE, download the test results in .CSV format and the logs
>       as a zip file from the Download Results link.