# VSTS and Jmter : Jmeter Load test script is not running on vsts as part of build process

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops

I have followed below links to run my JMeter Load test scripts on VSTS

[Link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/get-started-jmeter-test?view=vsts)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744216/unable-to-see-summary-post-the-jmeter-load-test-in-visual-studio-team-services)
    . Script ran successfully, however i did not see data on 'Summary' and 'Charts' tabs.

Please see attached screen shots.
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: what version of jmeter are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

VSTS only supports JMeter 3.2 as most up to date version.

So if you’re using more recent version, downgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I see data on 'Summary' and 'Charts' tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I see data on 'Summary' and 'Charts' tabs. I have downloaded DefaultCLTAttributes.csv from vsts and tried to open with JMeter.  I got error message -  'Error loading results file-see log file'. I did not see any error in log file.  Please help me

Comment: if answer is ok, you should accept it so that it’s useful to others. thanks

Comment: I see data on 'Summary' and 'Charts' tabs. I have downloaded DefaultCLTAttributes.csv from vsts and tried to open with JMeter. I got error message - 'Error loading results file-see log file'. I did not see any error in log file. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

In my case I made a downgrade of jmeter-4 to jmeter-3.2 and in Thread Group, I flag Loop Count, because jmeter tests finished before vsts might collect results.