# JMeter CI/CD process in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, jmeter

I have to create CI/CD pipeline in TFS 2017 to execute JMeter performance test.

I've created a build definition according to the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/configuring-jmeter-tests-in-vsts-tfs-azure-devops-and-publishing-results-dcdd7b451cb9) and a release definition (I have used created build definition as an artifact for the release definition).

After trying to create new release I get the following message: `Versions could not be loaded for all artifact sources. This could be due to inaccessible artifact source or artifact source has been deleted or no versions are available.`

Could someone help to fix it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting because it couldn’t access the artifact source anymore due to some reason.

- May like there are not available builds (deleted by retention policy)
  or your build definition renamed.
- Make sure your build definition has successful builds, and it has
  '**Publish Artifact**: drop' as the last task (Try both drop to the
  server and a file share).
- Another place you need to pay attention to is permission. Please
  double check your account and those groups which contain your account
  **have sufficient permission** to create release. Check if there are any deny setting, since deny trumps allow in TFS.

Set **Inheritance > On**, and then assigned full rights to the Administrators and Service groups in the Build (not Release). And this actually should bring back the drop-down content of artifacts versions in Releases.

Here are the documents which explains how to create the release definition and how to link the artifacts. Please kindly go through it in case you need:

- [Define your multi-stage continuous deployment (CD) pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops#variables)
- [Release artifacts and artifact sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#concepts)

Comment: Thank you @Patrick. Now I've met the following issue: when trying to run build definition, I get the following warn message in the TFS console: `Could not open Test.jmx`. On the agent, the test is running with no issues. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @user270219 warning is not like an error which will not fail build. If the test is running with no issues and build succeed. Besides, you could compare the test running locally with build agent. If you get the same result. You could simply ignore the warning. Sorry not familiar with JMeter, you could also check if your test is running for a very short duration. Kindly check if this link helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744216/unable-to-see-summary-post-the-jmeter-load-test-in-visual-studio-team-services